The problem with commutation relation
Quantum mechanics states that operators of general coordinate $Q$ and conjugate momenta $P$ obey commutation relations of the type $QP-PQ= i a I$, where $a$ is a constant factor and $I$ is the eigenoperator. According to the theory, operators of physical quantities are Hermitian in the Hilbert space. They have real eigenvalues and their eigenvectors form an orthonormal basis.
From the commutation relation it follows the uncertainty principle $D_Q D_P$ >= positive constant, where $D$ is the standard deviation of measurement outcome in a given state. If $Q$ had an eigenvector, in that state $D_Q=0$, since $Q$ is well-defined. However, this statement contradicts the uncertainty principle. $0 \times D_P$ can not be positive, since zero times anything can not be positive. This means that $Q$ can not have an eigenvector. The same argument is true for $P$ as well. $Q$ and $P$ can not represent physical quantities. Hence, quantum theory is inconsistent. What is the resolution of this problem?

Strictly speaking the position/momentum operators do not have eigenvectors. They have the so-called improper eigenvectors which are not normalizable and do not really belong to the Hilbert space. The mathematically rigorous way to deal with this is to use the von Neumann spectral theorem.

$I$ is the eigenoperator. Don’t you mean the identity operator?

Classic error.  The inequality holds only if the states are normalized, and the eigenstates of $Q$ are not - at least not normalized in the usual sense as they are outside the usual Hilbert space.  The eigenstates of $P$ for instance are planes waves $\sim e^{i PQ/\hbar}$ and are clearly not normalizable in the usual sense.
So: no contradiction because the assumptions underlying the inequality are not satisfied.  This is not the only situation where assumptions are violated; the most common assumptions is on self-adjointness of operators (see for instance this question ).

If the inequality only holds for normalizable states, then what justifies the usual uncertainty principle with $\Delta x$ and $\Delta p$?

You are correct to note that, when both Q and P have continuous spectrum, then both are non-normalisable and thus do not have eigenvectors within the usual Hilbert space. It is more interesting, however, if one of the operators have a discrete spectrum somewhere, in which case, there would be normalisable eigenvectors, but then the other operator would be complicated, e.g. having infinite spread. Infinite spread is the more usual conception that people would resolve this mental paradox.

@agaminon there is no problem evaluating $\Delta x$ or $\Delta p$ for harmonic oscillator states or for (normalizable) wave packets.  What matters is that the state used to evaluate $\Delta x$ and $\Delta p$ must be normalizable.

@naturallyInconsistent the post I linked to is such an example.  There things fail because of the self-adjoint condition.
